# The SMTP Address has no mailbox associated with it

Tags: c#, smtp, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, blueprism

I have been having issues accessing the shared mailbox with error The SMTP Address has no mailbox associated with it, though I can see the mailbox in the Outlook app. 
The both mailboxes are Office 365 mailboxes. I was having access before to the shared mailboxes mentioned above but through another mailbox and everything worked fine with my code. The thing worth mentioning is that I use this code inside Blue Prism. I am sorry but I am not a proper programmer so the code may be a little bit messy...any thoughts?

```
        public static ExchangeService CreateService(
        string user = "",
        string pass = ""
        )
    {
        bool success= false;
        string[] serviceURLs= new []{
        "yyy",
        "xxx",
        }; 
     string[] knownAutodiscoveryUrls = new [] {
        "qqq",
        "zzz",
        };
        var autodiscoveryUrlsList = new List<string>();
        autodiscoveryUrlsList.AddRange(knownAutodiscoveryUrls);


       foreach (string serviceURL in serviceURLs)

         {
            AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false); // only for DotNetCore 2.1 and up
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
            service.Url = new Uri(serviceURL);
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pass.Trim())) { service.UseDefaultCredentials = false; } else { service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(user, pass); }

            var findFolderResults = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(FolderSchema.TotalCount, 0), new FolderView(10));
            success=true;
            return service;

            //creates service with services URL

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex); 

        }

        if (success==false){

            try{

            var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
            service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user)) {
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(user, pass);
            }
            service.AutodiscoverUrl(user,RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
            if (service.Url == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(service.Url.ToString())) {

    const string baseMessage = "Failed to resolve valid ExchangeService object: service.Url property is either null or empty, meaning that no Exchange server was discovered!";
    if (autodiscoveryUrlsList.Any()) {
        throw new Exception(baseMessage + ". Tried following Autodiscover URL addresses: " + string.Join("; ", autodiscoveryUrlsList));
    } else {
        throw new Exception(baseMessage + ". Tried just to use classic ExchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(string mailbox) approach in order to detect the Exchange server, no custom Autodiscover URL addresses were tried.");
        }
}
            var findFolderResults = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(FolderSchema.TotalCount, 0), new FolderView(10));
            return service;
            }
```

For getting email from the mailbox I use this

```
        ExchangeService service = CreateService(user, pass);

        if (item.StartsWith("\\"))
        //Returns item form specific folder e.g \Inbox without knowing exact Email ID
        {
            folderId = GetFolderId(item, user,pass,mailbox);
            ItemView view = new ItemView(1);
            if (ascending) { view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Ascending); } else { view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending); }
            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(folderId, view);
            int itemCount = findResults.Count();
            if (itemCount == 0) { noEmail = true; Console.WriteLine("No email"); return; }
            else
            {
                noEmail = false;
            }

            itemId = findResults.Items[0].Id.UniqueId.ToString();
        }
        else { itemId = item; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your function CreateService() is missing following statement : 
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userEmailAddress, userPassword);

in foreach loop put following code :
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService()
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userEmailAddress, userPassword);

and give proper email address and password. Let me know if it works

Comment: service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(user, pass); I have this instead. The code worked fine before with another mailbox. and other functions are working as well.